# Places.PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace gives empty result and empty likelyplaces

Tags: android, google-places-api

```
private void getLocation()throws SecurityException {
    Log.e("TAG","Entered Get Location");
    PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>  result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
            if(mGoogleApiClient!=null)
            {
                Log.e("TAG","Client Not Null "+mGoogleApiClient.toString());
            }
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
            Log.e("TAG","Result  " +likelyPlaces.getCount());
            for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                Log.e("PLACES ",placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName().toString());
                tvLikelyPlaces.append(String.format("Place '%s' with " +
                                "likelihood: %g",
                        placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                        placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()) + "\n");
            }
            likelyPlaces.release();
        }
    });
}
```

I tried to log likelyplaces and it shows its empty, I have tried testing on a physical device. I do not get any other errors,

I am sure about my API settings and can connect successfully with Google Client API but it seems the Google Places API for Android has some issues.
I have mentioned ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION , INTERNET and READ_GSERVICES permission

Comment: do you have location permission

Comment: Yes FINE_LOCATION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by enabling Places api on the developer console 
**Google Map Api is different than Places api**